# Facebook plugin for Cordova doesn't post the image link from iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

I'm using Facebook plugin for Cordova and I just want to post a link using the "share" method.

The destination link has the correct Facebook metadata (og:title, og:image...etc).

The thing is that it works like a charm on Android: it posts the image and all the metadata correctly. 
On iOS the dialog shows the image and I publish it, but when I check my timeline the image is not posted (the title and description and the rest of information are posted).

What happens to the image? Why does it work on Android and it doesn't work on iOS? Is there anything I'm missing?

```
facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog({
            method: "share",
            quote: "¡Yolo!",
            hashtag: "#yolo",
            href: "http://lasonrisanomada.com",               
            mobile_iframe: true
          }, function (response) {
            console.log(response)
          }, function (response) {
            console.log(response)
          }
        );
```

I would appreciate your help so much.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send picture parameter also:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog({
        method: "share",
        quote: "¡Yolo!",
        hashtag: "#yolo",
        href: "http://lasonrisanomada.com",  
        picture: 'http://lasonrisanomada.com/image.png',             
        mobile_iframe: true
      }, function (response) {
        console.log(response)
      }, function (response) {
        console.log(response)
      }
    );
```

Comment: The "share" method doesn't have that parameter, that's the "feed" method. 
Anyway, the parameter "picture" of the method "feed" has been deprecated on 17th of July of this year unfortunately...